# Access another component DOM element from a separated competent in React avoiding to document.getElementById

Tags: javascript, reactjs, dom, single-page-application, react-dom

I have two different components in my React application.One component to display pop up, and other for text search field.
There is no relation(parent-child)between them.

My question is when user clicks pop up message(component), be focused text field in another component.

How can I handle this situation without using **document.getElementById**?
only using a react a specific way like **reactDOM with ref**.

Is it possible to handle like that?

Thanks

Answer (score 0):

Find the common parent component, and write a function which updates a state with ref of the element to be focused. Pass down that function as props to the second component. 
 And use `<input ref={r => this.props.func(r)`

Now on click of first component you can access this parent state.

Comment: thanks for the comment, in my scenario, there is no parent or child relation, these are two different components

Comment: Yeah these components will at least share a common parent, grant parent or grant grant parent. Usually people render an <App/> component using ReactDom.render . That means App is a common parent for all your components .

Comment: you can achieve this using redux